# Python-Browsermobproxy: unable to collect har data

Tags: python, json, selenium, browsermob-proxy, har

I have to write a generalized codebase to track some specific data from a website. For this, I have used browsermob-proxy. After completing the page interactions using selenium, I try to dump the data in a result object using json.dumps. The code which is Use to do it is

`result = json.dumps(proxy.har, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')`

The reason to do is that I want to store the data to someplace so that I may apply some operations to the file and get the required response data. But after all the processing for webdriver gets completed, it gives me the error

python_error

[image]

I am not sure why is it giving this error

What I decoded is there is no JSON object that could be decoded for which I am getting this error.

Environment: MacOs Sierra
Python version: 2.7
BrowserMob_Proxy: 0.8.0